# Pull to refresh in UICollectionView in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I used the following code at a `UICollectionViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {            

    self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    let refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refreshStream", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    refreshControl = refresher
    collectionView!.addSubview(refreshControl!)
}

func refreshStream() {

    print("refresh")
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

}
```

Now I need it to work with a `UICollectionView` inside a `UIViewController` and I googled for an hour now but can't get it working.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Isn't it work?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678727/uirefreshcontrol-on-uicollectionview-only-works-if-the-collection-fills-the-heig

Comment: The main code is objective c and the swift comments gets me a lot issues:

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'Const'

Comment: Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView'

Comment: this error says the the collectionview is not a member class in current class , so do like in view didload `self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "xxxx", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "xxxx")`

Comment: well, if I enter that code, I'm again getting "Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView'"

Comment: my header is: class NewBlogViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {..}

Comment: see this for iOS 10 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483511/uirefreshcontrol-with-uicollectionview-in-ios7/37865309#37865309

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the storyboard, you need to link the collection view to the appropriate controller file, using Ctrl + Drag from the collection view object. It needs to be linked via an @IBOutlet.

Also, you should Ctrl + Drag from the collection view to the view controller object on the storyboard and select Data Source and Delegate so that the collection view is correctly linked.

Let me know if this helps or if I have misunderstood your situation.

Comment: hell yeah! thank you pal. the outlet dit it. thank you!

Answer (score 73):

New swift code changed in calling action method you could do rewrite like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var refresher:UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    self.refresher.tintColor = UIColor.red
    self.refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loadData), for: .valueChanged)
    self.collectionView!.addSubview(refresher)
}

@objc func loadData() {
   self.collectionView!.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
   //code to execute during refresher
       .
       .
       .
   stopRefresher()         //Call this to stop refresher
 }

func stopRefresher() {
   self.collectionView!.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, but "var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!" need change to "var refresher:UIRefreshControl!"

Comment: rather than ```addSubview(refresher)```, the swift3 way of adding this refresher to a collection is:

```self.collectionView!.refreshControl = refresher
self.collectionView!.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
self.collectionView!.refreshControl.endRefreshing()```

Comment: @KingChintz collectionView.refreshControl is only available in iOS10. addSubview works across more version.

Comment: Doesn't `let refresher = UIRefreshControl()` create a local instance of `UIRefreshControl` for `viewDidLoad` only? shouldn't it be `self.refresher = UIRefreshControl()` The code as is wouldn't run the stopRefresher correctly

Answer (score 26):

## Swift 5 solution

As @fishspy already mentioned, that's the way to put your collection view inside a view controller, but I'm gonna share also how to connect your refresh control to the collection view in a cleaner way.

Since iOS 10 there's a dedicated property for the refresh control. Apart of that, I'd also recommend to directly initialise your refresh control as a property, declaring it private and doing the following things:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPullToRefresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl // iOS 10+
}

@objc
private func didPullToRefresh(_ sender: Any) {
    // Do you your api calls in here, and then asynchronously remember to stop the
    // refreshing when you've got a result (either positive or negative)
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: I've never seen an horizontal pull-to-refresh honestly, so no as far as I know

Comment: For anyone who needs this, I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614319/is-it-possible-to-add-a-drag-to-reload-horizontally-for-a-collection-view

Answer (score 21):

```
var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
      self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
     self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PricingPlansCollectionViewController.reload), for: .valueChanged)
      collectionView!.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

 func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
  {
    //DO 
  }
```

Comment: Your Code wants me to put in an semicolone betweet "ValueChanged)   collectionView!" ----> Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: You should be setting the refresh control object to the `refreshControl` property of your collectionView [per the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol)

Answer (score 2):

For me, i had:

```
func setupCollectionView(){
      self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
      self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refreshing content...")
      self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.reload), for: .valueChanged)
      collectionView!.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

It still wasn't working (I believe i had constraints preventing it somehow), so i added:

```
collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

then all was good. Just in case someone else is facing the same issue.

For a better understanding, the full implementation

```
@IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 setupCollectionView()
}

func setupCollectionView(){
      collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.dataSource = self
      collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
      self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
      self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refreshing content...")
      self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .valueChanged)
      collectionView!.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

 @objc func refresh(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    //do refreshing stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(youFunction), for: .valueChanged)
   
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Fetching Data ...", attributes: nil)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
       yourCollectionViewOrTableView.reloadData()
 }
```