# Subclassing a variable within a class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the behavior of a variable within a class.

To be more precise, I have a 'UIWebView' which has a 'scrollview' property.

I need to override the 'setContentInset' of this scrollview, however I'm not sure how to do this.

The docs show me the UIWebView has this:

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView { get }
```

So I can't simply create my own and set it there.

My question is, how do I override the 'setContentInset' from the UIWebView's scrollview?

**Edit:**

2 clarifications.

I know the UIWebView is NOT supposed to be subclassed, as per the documentation's [subclassing notes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2).

My goal is to fix the "pull down to refresh" jumpy behavior following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483511/uirefreshcontrol-with-uicollectionview-in-ios7/19926917#19926917) that I already implemented on my app's other scrollviews.

Comment: I don't know if you can achieve what you want, but as a workaround consider extending the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol to add a delegate method `scrollViewDidSetContentInset(UIScrollView)`, then extend `UIScrollView` to call it whenever `contentInset` is set.

Answer (score 0):

When a built-in interface class "has" another built-in interface class, you cannot subclass the inner class or override anything about it.

Thus, although you can subclass UIWebView, you cannot somehow subclass a UIWebView's scroll view.

Another familiar example is UIButton. Everyone knows that UIButton contains a UILabel and a UIImageView. You can subclass UIButton but you can't subclass its UILabel or UIImageView.

Comment: It would be tricky to override `titleLabel` and `imageView` of `UIButton`, but that's because of the different button states. I have successfully overridden both `textLabel` and `imageView` in subclasses of `UITableViewCell`. What problems would you expect when overriding `scrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a straight forward approach, and see if there are any subtle problems.

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {
    private lazy var my_contentInset: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets()
    override var contentInset: UIEdgeInsets {
        get { return my_contentInset }
        set {
            // Your willSet code
            my_contentInset = newValue
            // Your didSet code
        }
    }
}

class MyWebView: UIWebView {
    private lazy var my_scrollView: MyScrollView = MyScrollView()
    override var scrollView: UIScrollView {
        get { return my_scrollView }
    }
}
```

This is a bit simplistic, so you may run into problems depending how the runtime sets `scrollView`. If the runtime expects a setter for `scrollView`, then you'll need to get deeper.

Here I create a initializer for my scroll view which clones a `UIScrollView` and uses that in the setter for `MyWebView`'s `scrollView`.

```
extension MyScrollView {
    convenience init(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: scrollView)
        let coder = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
        self.init(coder: coder)! // Intentionally failing hard on decode failure.

        // Additional configuration not captured in the encode/decode
        // process might be needed.
    }
}

class MyWebView: UIWebView {
    private lazy var my_scrollView: MyScrollView = MyScrollView()
    override var scrollView: UIScrollView {
        get { return my_scrollView }
        set { my_scrollView = MyScrollView(scrollView: newValue) }
    }
}
```

Even this might not be enough. The runtime can cheat in lots of ways when dealing with internal objects. It should be enough to get you started.